# how to bind an object to treeview?

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, mvvm, treeview

I'm trying to bind an object (that fetched from db) to treeview control.

My object stracture is somethings like this :

```
public class Post
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { set; get; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Post> SubPosts { get; set; }
}
```

I defined a method that get data from db and put that in a property of my class:

My Property :

```
private Post _posts;
public Post Posts
{
    set
    {
        _posts = value;
        InvokePropertyChanged("Posts");
    }
    get { return _posts; }
}
```

then

```
Posts = _orgChartModel.GetOrgChartByParentId(1);
```

Now,I want to bind the "Posts" property to a treeview.

XAML code :

```
<sdk:TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}">
<sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubPosts}" >
        <StackPanel >
            <Image Width="48" Height="48" 
                Source="/CalendarClass;component/Assets/person.png" />
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

My code does not work,What's wrong?

Comment: "that's not work". What does this mean exactly?

Comment: You're still not explaining. What doesn't work? Are you getting an empty tree? Are you getting binding errors?

Comment: Can you try to put `Mode = TwoWay` into the bindings. This fixed the problem for me as far as I can remember.

Comment: I tried it but did not changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ItemSource property of TreeView expects a type of IEnumerable. Your binding to a single Post, which is why it's not working. Change your Posts binding property to be a collection of posts:

```
private ObservableCollection<Post> _posts;
public ObservableCollection<Post> Posts
{
    set
    {
        _posts = value;
        InvokePropertyChanged("Posts");
    }
    get { return _posts; }
}
```

Then initialize your binding property and just in case the view doesn't pick up that the Posts changed, bind your treeview again:

```
  Posts = new ObservableCollection<Post>();
  var post = _orgChartModel.GetOrgChartByParentId(1);
  Posts.Add(post);
  treeView.ItemsSource = Posts; //or whatever the name of your TreeView control is.
```